# lock the physical location file storage for the uploaded

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

Need to lock the physical location file storage for the uploaded. On server, web admin have the access of the file which are stored. Need to lock the folder so none can access the folder other than the system.

I can lock the folder using privilege but it is not allowing to upload the file using servlet.

is anybody have idea about it? How can I achieve security of folder? is there any solution other than database storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the security measures of the file system to do this. Eg on Linux, create a group and only give r/w access to this group with regards to your upload folder. Run your servlet container with a user that is a member of this group.

Comment: thank you for reply. that's mean suppose app folder under /webapp/{app folder}/standalone/filename.txt. file uploaded under standalone folder which has write permission for others. so from this they can also have read permission default. so how can I do secure folder?